# x != y of type Y when checking that the pattern p(y) has type Z

Tags: agda

I'm getting a strange error of the form `x != y of type Y when checking that the pattern p(y) has type Z`. I do not know why or how I'm getting this and would like to solve the issue. A problem instance follows; thank-you.

---

Suppose I've a set,

```
postulate A : Set
```

and a way to interpret its elements as sets,

```
postulate F : A → Set
```

Then using pairs of that set,

```
record B : Set where field s t : A
```

I can build a parametrised type on it:

```
data C : A → Set where MkC : (b : B) → F (B.s b) → C (B.t b)
```

Now I'd like to, for example, form a function

```
ABCF : ∀ a → (f : A → A) → C a → C (f a)
ABCF t f e = {!!}
```

and I'd do so by pattern matching on the third argument via `C-c C-c`
and doing so gets me

```
ABCF .(B.t b) f (MkC b x) = {!!}
```

then another `C-c C-c`, on `b`, yields

```
ABCF t f (MkC record { s = s ; t = .t } x) = ?
```

**but** this casing is immediately followed by an error:

```
B.t b != t of type A
when checking that the pattern MkC record { s = s ; t = .t } x has
type C t
```

Replacing `.t` with `t'` also does not solve this.

Any help indicating the reason behind this error and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated!

---

**Edit**

As answered below, the above problem may be due to a bug, but what of the converse case?

```
FCBA : ∀ {a} (f : A → A) → C (f a) → C a
FCBA {a} f (MkC record { s = s ; t = .(f a) } x) = ?
```

How would we solve this one? Which comes with the error

```
B.t b != f a of type A
when checking that the pattern MkC record { s = s ; t = .(f a) } x
has type C (f a)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug. If you swap the inaccessible pattern with the regular one, everything works:

```
ABCF : ∀ a → (f : A → A) → C a → C (f a)
ABCF .t f (MkC record { s = s ; t = t } x) = {!!}
```

But that `a` should anyway be implicit, since it's always inferrable from `C a`. Then there is no problem:

```
ABCF : ∀ {a} → (f : A → A) → C a → C (f a)
ABCF f (MkC record { s = s ; t = t } x) = {!!}
```

---

If you cannot pattern match directly due to the type being too specific, you can generalize it:

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

FCBA : ∀ {a} (f : A → A) → C (f a) → C a
FCBA {a} f c with f a | inspect f a | c
... | .b | [ r ] | MkC record { s = s ; t = b } x = {!!}
```

Here we generalize `f a` to `b` and remember that `f a ≡ b` (in this case such remembering is not useful probably, but it's needed if you don't want to forget that `b` is actually `f a`). This allows to pattern match on `c` with swapping the inaccessible and the regular patterns like before.

But this is not a trick — it's an ugly hack. You should probably ask on the Agda mailing list why this swapping is required and whether this is the intended behavior.

Comment: The idea of switching the position of the dot is a trick I'll try to keep in mind. It seems that I've phrased my problem in reverse; would you please look at the edit above.